# SQL Server: sp_describe_first_result_set with more than one select in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, metadata

I'm using `sp_describe_first_result_set` to retrive metadata from a stored procedure and having the following error:

```
Msg 11512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
The metadata could not be determined because the statement 'SELECT 1' in procedure 'test' is not compatible with the statement 'SELECT 'str'' in procedure 'test'.
```

This SP can return different datasets depending on a parameter:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @test NVARCHAR(50) = 'test'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@test = 'test')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'str'
    END
END
```

Looks like `sp_describe_first_result_set` does an `UNION` of the queries because if both the queries returns the same col model, the procedure works.

I've even tried to pass `@parameter` like this:

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(50) = 'test2'
EXEC [dbo].[sp_describe_first_result_set]
    @tsql = N'test @test = @test'
    ,@params = N'@test NVARCHAR(50)'
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is expected and is described on the `sp_describe_first_result_set` doc under the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section:

> For each control flow path, the first statement (if any) that returns
> a result set is determined by sp_describe_first_result_set.
>
> When multiple possible first statements are found in a batch, their
> results can differ in number of columns, column name, nullability, and
> data type. How these differences are handled is described in more
> detail here:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the data type differs, an error will be thrown and no result is    returned except for the following cases:
>
>   - **varchar(a)** to **varchar(a')** where a' > a.
>   - **varchar(a)** to **varchar(max)**
>   - **nvarchar(a)** to **nvarchar(a')** where a' > a.
>   - **nvarchar(a)** to **nvarchar(max)**
>   - **varbinary(a)** to **varbinary(a')** where a' > a.
>   - **varbinary(a)** to **varbinary(max)**

The doc has an example where an [Error because the data types differ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#error-because-the-data-types-differ) happens, like in your case.